# ASP.NET hostingEnvironment / shadowCopyBinAssemblies

Tags: asp.net, assemblies, web-config

Today I stumpled upon the **shadowCopyBinAssemblies** option in the **[hostingEnvironment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228159.aspx)** tag.

Appearently this attribute it is a **web.config** (system.web) configuration Boolean option indicating whether the assemblies of an application in the Bin directory are shadow copied to the application's ASP.NET Temporary Files directory.

```
<hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" />
```

A colleague [had to enable this setting](http://dotnetsoldier.blogspot.com/2008/09/cannot-create-shadow-copy-visual-studio_1635.html) because (only) on his development machine he frequently got that ASP.NET error in the web browser:

```
 Cannot create shadow copy assembly file dll when that file already exists.
```

compiling a specific web project in Visual Studio 2008 and openining a page.

So now my question: can I preserve this setting **in a production environment** or could it harm performance and/or create other issues?

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get this error from time to time, and usually doing **Clean Solution** followed by **Rebuild Solution** takes care of the problem.  If this works for your colleague, then there's no need to play with the setting (especially in production).

Comment: Any answer to the original question about that setting causing harm in a production environment?

Comment: On the contrary, performance is apparently improved, but the application locks the DLLs while running. See this explanation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gduthie/archive/2006/11/09/tip-shadow-copy-and-your-bin-directory.aspx